# Oracle, For cicle with a dinamic table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hy Guys,

i have a problem with a Cursor, i can't find a solution.

i would like to do a second loop like in the code, where i loop dynamically for the table found above but return that error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP".
i am starting with pl-sql.

Can you give me some suggestions for fix that problem?
thx, all.

```
CURSOR V_LIST_TABLES IS
SELECT
OBJECT_TYPE,
OWNER ||'.'|| OBJECT_NAME AS SCHEMA,
OBJECT_NAME
FROM DBA_OBJECTS U
WHERE OWNER = 'MYSCHEMA'
AND OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE');

BEGIN

FOR INDX_CURSOR IN V_LIST_TABLES LOOP

    IF INDX_CURSOR.OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%TEST%' THEN

        FOR INDX_CURSOR_2 IN ('SELECT * FROM' || INDX_CURSOR.OBJECT_NAME) LOOP
        
            NULL;
            -- DO SOMETHINGS
            
        END LOOP;
        
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: In your inner cursor, remove the single quotes from around the SELECT * FROM.  With the quotes, it's just a string, not a SELECT statement.

Comment: EdStevens, if i remove, the single quotes, after the error is ORA-00903 the name of table is not valid, becouse the name of table is passed from a variable

Comment: What are you going to do in the inner loop?  Doing a `select *` when different tables have different numbers of columns and data types would imply that your inner cursor likely needs to be opened and processed via `dbms_sql`.  If that is just a placeholder, there may be a simpler approach using `execute immediate` or something even simpler.

Comment: i should write on file (UTL_FILE) the value of different fields associated with tables

Comment: " is ORA-00903 the name of table is not valid",  Well, _with_ the quotes, your IN list is not the result of a query, it is the characater literal 'SELECT * FROM', concatenated to a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this way more complex than it need be.

```
vsql varchar2(200);
vfname varchar2(20);
vlname varchar2(20);
vdob date;
For x in (select owner,
                 table_name
          from dba_tables
          where owner = 'MYSCHEMA'
            and table_name like '%TEST%'
          )
loop
   -- do something with x.owner and x.table_name
   vsql := 'select fname, lname, dob into vfname, vlname, vdob from '||
           x.owner||'.'||x.table_name;
   dbms_output.put_line(vsql);  -- debug only
   execute vsql;
end loop;
```

Comment: Hy, inside the variable vsql you have assumed that all tables have the same fields, but is not true.